# SharePoint 2010 and FBA

Tags: sharepoint, forms-authentication, sharepoint-2010, claims-based-identity

I an trying to setup Forms Based Authentication using ASPNetSQLMembershipProvider.
In 2010 Beta 2, I was able to do this in classic mode, and it worked.
With the RTM, it is no longer supported under classic mode, and I must switch to Claims based Authentication.
So I created a new web application, and configured everything in sharepoint to work with FBA, But I can't get it to work.

Anyone managed to do this?

Thanks,
Itay.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible.  I blogged all the details [here](http://donalconlon.wordpress.com/2010/02/23/configuring-forms-base-authentication-for-sharepoint-2010-using-iis7/).  Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use ready-made solutions for the management of FBA users, you should take a look here:

http://www.devit.eu/products/121-fba-manager-sp2010-forms-based-authentication.aspx